# google cloud HTTPS load balancer session affinity

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, load-balancing, google-cloud-networking

I have an HTTPS load balancer configured with one backend service and 2 instance groups:

The backend is configured for cookie session affinity.

My transaction is made out of a POST request and then 6 redirects which requires session affinity. In most case this works as expected but in about 10%-15% of the cases the affinity stops working during the redirection sequence which results in an application error on our side.

I'm printing the GCLB cookie value on our Apache reverse proxy and can see that it's not changing between requests but the request is still redirected to a different instance in the group or from a different group(note that the same behaviour is happening when there is only a single group with multiple instances in the backend.)

The health checks are all passing and there is no autoscaling happening during the run(1 instance per group).

What can cause the LB to change backend instances although the GCLB cookie is not different?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-service#losing_session_affinity) says there are three causes for loss of session affinity:

- The instance group runs out of capacity, and traffic has to be routed to a different zone. In this case, traffic from existing sessions may be sent to the new zone, breaking affinity. You can mitigate this by ensuring that your instance groups have enough capacity to handle all local users.
- Autoscaling adds instances to, or removes instances from, the instance group. In either case, the backend service reallocates load, and the target may move. You can mitigate this by ensuring that the minimum number of instances provisioned by autoscaling is enough to handle expected load, then only using autoscaling for unexpected increases in load.
- The target instance fails health checks. Affinity is lost as the session is moved to a healthy instance.

If the number of instances in the IG isn't changing, and all instances are remaining healthy the entire time, then that eliminates the second and third bullet points.

Are you using a [regional managed instance group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/distributing-instances-with-regional-instance-groups)? If so, the first bullet point seems to be the cause.

It could be possible that you're tickling some sort of bug in the session cookie handling; to eliminate this possibility, have you tried other affinity settings to see if the problem goes away?

Comment: yes, I'm using regional managed instance group and have tested with multiple configurations and whenever there is more than instance in the group it occasionally loses the affinity. I've tried with client IP affinity and it behaved similarly and also tried with the group setup to min=3 and max=3 in-order to test with 1 node per zone but results are always the same. I can't rule out health checks but they all return 200 in my proxy logs and there are no logs in GCP that I can verify this on. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Right now, you can't view instance health history from within Cloud Console. If you open a ticket with support, we can see that and let you know. The DIY approach would be to watch your backend service carefully, perhaps scripting [`gcloud compute backend-services get-health servicename`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/backend-services/get-health) once every couple of seconds over the course of a few days, grepping the output for `UNHEALTHY` and letting you know, perhaps adding a timestamp. At that point you can correlate that to any loss of affinity.

Comment: ok, so I ran get-health during the test(every 2 seconds) and all the instances remain healthy. I then decided to try with Client IP affinity again and it actually worked properly and all the requests were sent to the same instance. As soon as I'm using the cookie affinity it goes back to switching nodes so definitely something to do with cookie affinity logic. I'll open a support ticket to try and get to the bottom of this.

Comment: @imeib Great! If my answer helped you, please **both** upvote **and** accept it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

We also faced the same issue and came to this stack overflow question and answer. After days of playing with settings and configuration, again referred to google [docs](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#losing_session_affinity). Now, there can be 4 reasons why this can happen. Our issue got resolved by 4th cause. We changed from Utilization to RPS. Speciafically

> When the UTILIZATION balancing mode is in effect for backend instance groups, session affinity breaks because of changes in backend utilization. You can mitigate this by using the RATE or CONNECTION balancing mode, whichever is supported by the load balancer's type.